# Sort products by image first and by name ASC

Tags: mysql

I have a table with products, some products have images, some of them don’t. I have to sort these products by name ASC but first products should be these with an image (field isn’t empty string), and after that it should list the products without image, also name ASC. Thanks for help in advance!

Comment: How are images "stored"? It would go faster if you provide your database structure for the tables needed in your query, and some expected output based on same example data in tables...

Comment: *field isn’t empty string* image field is a string type contained image path or a blob containing whole image? If first, `ORDER BY image = '', name`, if second, `ORDER BY image is NULL, name`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggest an additional sorting column, `imgsort`, used as the first
criteria for the ORDER BY clause. Something along these lines:

```
   SELECT 
       fields, ...
       , IF(image="",0,1) as `imgsort`
   FROM ...
   ORDER BY `imgsort` DESC, ...
   ;
```

Comment: More simply:  `ORDER BY image="", name`